# How can I decode escaped characters to the original string input in Python?

Tags: python, string, python-re

I am using some string from chatGPT to generate latex code, the problem is that sometimes the function in latex will have the double backslash and sometimes it doesent, so for example sometimes I will get `"\\fraction{1}{2}"`, which works as intended because you need to give double backslash to escape it, but sometimes the string will be `"\fraction{1}{2}"`, and this will show as `"\x0craction{1}{2}"`, transforming the `"\f"` into `"\x0c"`.

So what i need is a way to transform back this `\x0c` into `"\f"` and any other possible case similar to this.

I do not need to delete the scaped character, I want to retreive the orignal input.

Comment: Were you using the same function and code logic to fetch the response from chatGPT? If so, then that probably means that chatGPT is somewhat inconsistent in its latex formatting.

Comment: Yes i was using the same input for chatGPT, sometimes is right and sometimes is not